# Need to show index number for lamps that have value of 0

Tags: c, printf

my code shows all 100 "lights" with values of 1 and 0, what I need to do (and not managing to..) is to show only the lights which has value of 0 (so it's these lights [and these numbers are what needs to be shown] 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100).
Thanks for the help.

The current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define lights 100
int main()
{
    int arr[lights] = { 0 }, i, j;
    printf("Lights that are off:\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= lights; i++)
        arr[i] = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= lights; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j <= lights; j += i)
        {
            if (arr[j] == 0)
                arr[j] = 1;
            else if (arr[j] == 1)
                arr[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= lights; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    return 0;
    _getch;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate a square of a number? I have no idea what your nested loops are doing.

Comment: OT: array indexes go from 0  to `lights-1` so `i <= lights` and `j <= lights` must be changed to `<`

Comment: On the first loop, it turns off all of the lights (since they were on - 1) and changes them to 0, on the second loop it jumps each time two lamps and flips the switch (so if it was 1 now it will be 0) and so on for third time (jumping 3 lights) until 100.

Comment: Your code matches the description in the comment. It does not seem related at all to the question title and also not to the list of numbers you show (which might be square numbers). If I understand correctly then lights which have a 0 are on automatically, which makes the question title even more confusing.

Comment: Are prime numbers involved here? I ask because if you delete the `if (arr[j] == 0)
                arr[j] = 1;
            else if (arr[j] == 1)` then you have an (inefficient) sieve for determining prime numbers.

Comment: Sorry my English might not be so good.. I'll just tell the question - There are 100 lamps (all are turned on - 1). one person decided to flip the switches as follow - first time he flips all the switches (now everything is off - 0), second time he flips the switches for second, fourth, sixth, eighth and so on lamps, third time he does the same but with skips of three, fourth time with skips of four and so on until the loop is over. What I did does show which are 1's and which are 0's, I need to show only the lamps that are off. The lamps that are off are sqrt numbers, but this isn't important

Comment: Usually an array indexing loop would run `for(i = 0; i < lights; i++)` but it is perfectly valid to run `for(i = 1; i <= lights; i++)` if that makes the problem easier. However the array needs to be `int arr[lights+1]`

Comment: @Yunnosch Prime numbers are not involved here, at least not directly. The number of divisors is much more important (each divisor of the lamp index toggles the lamp, and only perfect squares have odd numbers of them).

Comment: Are you familiar with the [modulus operator](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you're trying to solve the light bulb puzzle.
There's a good solution here: http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/six.htm

I've fixed your code so that it works, you have to be careful with the indexing.

```
#define NUM_OF_LIGHTS             (100)

void main(void)
{
  int bulbs[NUM_OF_LIGHTS] = { 0 };
  int i, j;

  for (i = 1; i < (NUM_OF_LIGHTS + 1); i++)
  {
    for (j = i; j < (NUM_OF_LIGHTS + 1); j += i)
    {
      /* Toggle the indexed bulb.
       * Note: adjust the array as it runs from 0 to 99, not 1 to 100.
       */
      bulbs[j - 1] ^= 1;
    }
  }
  /* Print out the result. */
  printf("Lights that are off:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LIGHTS; i++)
  {
    /* Only showing the bulb index for lights that are switched off. */
    if (bulbs[i] == 0)
    {
      printf("%d ", i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```